# i am using owl carousel in angular bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular

i am using owl carousel in angular bootstrap. i have used 2 owl slider in first owl slider i have used 1.5 type of list item and that slider is working properly.
but the second slider is not working if i used 4.5 type of list item.

first slider ts code

```
export const customOptionsForBigSlider:OwlOptions = {
    loop:true,
    center:true,
    dots: false,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,    
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:4000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,    
    navText: ["<img src='assets/img/carousel_left.png'>","<img src='assets/img/carousel_right.png'>"],
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:1
        },
        1000:{
            items:1.15
        }
    }
  }
```

second slider ts code

```
  export const customOptionsForFourMiniSlider:OwlOptions =  {
    loop: true,
    mouseDrag: false,
    touchDrag: false,
    pullDrag: false,
    margin:10,
    dots: false,
    nav: true,
    navSpeed: 700,
    navText: ["<img src='assets/img/carousel_left.png'>","<img src='assets/img/carousel_right.png'>"],
    responsive:{
      0:{
          items:1.5
      },
      600:{
          items:3.5
      },
      1000:{
          items:4.5
      }
    }
  }
```